# Ways to test POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED/ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED receiver

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have registered 2 receivers ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED and ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED.

For testing purposes, I was able to force ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED using `"adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle"` command, but am not able to test ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED mode.

Below is the receiver code incase needed:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M) @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            if (pm.isDeviceIdleMode()) {
                CLog.d(TAG, "Device Idle Mode");
            } else {
                CLog.d(TAG, "Not in Device Idle Mode");
            }
    }
  };

  registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED));

  BroadcastReceiver receiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M) @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            if (pm.isPowerSaveMode()) {
                CLog.d(TAG, "In Power Save Mode");
            } else {
                CLog.d(TAG, "Not in Power Save Mode");
            }
    }
  };

  registerReceiver(receiver2, new IntentFilter(PowerManager.ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED));
}
```

Is there a way to test ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED via terminal or using some other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try toggling the Battery Saver mode on your phone? The intents are broadcasted when there is change in the **power save mode** According to the documentation at

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isPowerSaveMode()

ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED:

*"Intent that is broadcast when the state of isPowerSaveMode() changes. This broadcast is only sent to registered receivers."*

isPowerSaveMode():

*"Returns true if the device is currently in power save mode. When in this mode, applications should reduce their functionality in order to conserve battery as much as possible. You can monitor for changes to this state with ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED."*

Comment: I later tried power save option from the menu on top of the device and that worked..

Comment: Great! I guess you're all set then!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way to test `ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED` using adb commands.

---

**From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/test-power#adb-battery)**:

To simulate the device being unplugged, use the command:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
```

To test how the device behaves under low power conditions, use this command:

```
$ adb shell settings put global low_power 1
```

Once you have finished your testing, you can undo your manual device settings with this command:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

On my Pixel XL (Android 10) device I've also had to manually change the `low_power` property back to 0 (the above battery reset command did not triggered broadcast with isPowerSaveMode = false):

```
$ adb shell settings put global low_power 0
```